# Change the sign of all elements of a ndarray meeting a condition

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Quick question on NumPy arrays. I have an array `c = np.arange(2,50,5)` and I should make all the numbers not divisible by 3 negative.

My code so far only converts the numbers not divisible by three (3) into negative numbers, but I need all of the values in the original array, c, to show up. That is, I need to convert all of the indivisible numbers into negatives while conserving those numbers that ARE divisible by three.

```
c = np.arange(2,50,5)

[-1* i for i in c if i % 3 != 0]
```

Comment: Can you please make the title a bit more compact? I think the "Hi all... Quic question ... " is not really necessary here. You probably better include the question in the question text as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of masking here:

```
c = np.arange(2,50,5)
c[c % 3 != 0] = -c[c % 3 != 0]
```

Or we can make use of the fact that `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`, by writing this as:

```
c = np.arange(2,50,5)
c = (2 * (c % 3 == 0) - 1) * c
```

Probably the former is however preferable over the latter, since it is more declarative and describes what it is doing.

Both give us:

```
>>> c
array([ -2,  -7,  12, -17, -22,  27, -32, -37,  42, -47])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.arange(2,50,5)
c[c%3!=0]=-c[c%3!=0]
```

with `c%3!=0` I get a boolean array with `False` when `c%3 = 0` (hence `c` divisible by `3`).

Comment: @MichelleDeLuna my please! Please do not forget to upvote helful answers and to accept one anwer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`, which is intuitive for this case:

```
c = np.arange(2,50,5)
c = np.where(c%3 != 0, -c, c)
```